# Selenium reading a link as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

As a Selenium exercise (still learning how to use it), I've been trying to get it to open chrome in headless mode, go to this site: https://adobe-flash-player.en.softonic.com/download and then click that download button ("Free Download for Windows").

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

options= Options()
options.headless=True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"
print(os.getcwd())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get("https://adobe-flash-player.en.softonic.com/download")
lucky_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn--medium btn--free-download mb-s track-btn-download")
print(lucky_button)
lucky_button.click()
```

It gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aniru/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/falsdwn.py", line 15, in <module>
    lucky_button.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

It seems to be reading that button to be a list, but if so, I cannot fathom why. How would I go about solving this, and why is this happening?

Comment: can you paste the html please ??

Comment: As check there is four classes there, try only with "btn--free-download"

Comment: functions `find_elements_by_...` with char `s` in word `elements` find all elements and they always create list - and you have to use index (ie. `[0]`) or `for`-loop. There are also functions `find_element_by_...` without char `s` in word `element` and they give only first element and you don't need `[0]`

Comment: @furas That made sense to me, but when I tried that (as an answer has also suggested), it turned out that the list itself came out to be empty even though there is clearly an element with that class name on that page.

Comment: maybe element is in `<iframe>` and Selenium treats it is as separated page and you have to find <iframe>` and use `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`. OR it uses JavaScript and it needs to wait few seconds before it will be available. OR it treats this name as single class and it needs `.` to treats as many classes - `"btn.btn--medium.btn--free-download.mb-s.track-btn-download"`

Answer (score 3):

To click on download button use either of the following css selector.

**Code:**

```
lucky_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn--medium.btn--free-download.mb-s.track-btn-download")
lucky_button.click()
```

OR

```
lucky_button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-auto='download-button']")
lucky_button.click()
```

---

**Update:**

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and induce javascripts executor to click on the button.

```
lucky_button=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn.btn--medium.btn--free-download.mb-s.track-btn-download")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",lucky_button)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

**Update:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
#provide your download path
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'D:\kk\Downloads'}) 
driver.get("https://adobe-flash-player.en.softonic.com/download") 

download_button=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn.btn--medium.btn--free-download.mb-s.track-btn-download")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",download_button)
print("Done")
```

Link you can find discussion here [Downloading file in headless mode](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5722)

Comment: Okay so first off: Thank You! This at least seemed to click that download button and brought up the post-download page (I know this since I had some code to click a screeshot at the end of the process, after the clicking, and it showed me the post-download page). However, it did not actually download the file :(

Comment: But that element, for whatever reason, is *not* clickable. See my answer. Did you test this?

Comment: Huh? I tried your code, and it did click that Download button (otherwise how would I have obtained the post-download page at the end of the process?). Which is good, since I couldnt manage even that earlier. But the issue is, that while it is clicking on it and taking me to the post-download page, it isn't actually downloading the file. Is this something to do with headless browser or what?

Comment: @AnirudhMishra : Can you try the updated answer and let me know the status?

Comment: Sadly, no. It did what your previous code was doing, i.e, it did seem to click that button and went through to the post-download page (and took a screenshot of that page). But it still did not download what it should have, at least not in the place where chrome normally downloads stuff.

Comment: @AnirudhMishra: I did try with interactive mode and it is working fine. Can you try with interactive mode first? This is working fine here.

Comment: What do you mean by working fine? Is chrome downloading the 'flash player' file to where chrome normally downloads file? And in headless mode, not normal.

Comment: @AnirudhMishra : Since you are getting  `keep or discard" message` in headless mode you need to inject `Chrome Devtools Protocol command` to get it downloaded.Try updated code and let me know.

Comment: @AnirudhMishra : I have just removed that line accept button pop-up. Now try the code.

Answer (score 1):

For opening Chrome in headless mode, I use:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
```

Second issue (your exception):

```
lucky_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn--medium btn--free-download mb-s track-btn-download")
if len(lucky_button): # found at least one
    lucky_button[0].click() # use first one
```

**Update**

I am not sure why your `find_elements_by_class_name` did not work. This, however, did seem to find something that was clickable (**but not consistently**, unfortunately):

```
lucky_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Free Download')
```

So instead of:

```
lucky_buttons[0].click()
```

Use:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lucky_buttons[0])
```

The complete code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.headless=True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get("https://adobe-flash-player.en.softonic.com/download")
    lucky_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Free Download')
    print(lucky_buttons)
    if len(lucky_buttons):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lucky_buttons[0])
finally:
    input('pausing ...')
    driver.quit()
```

**Update 2**

```
from selenium import webdriver

options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get("https://adobe-flash-player.en.softonic.com/download")
    lucky_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Free Download')
    print(lucky_buttons)
    if len(lucky_buttons):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lucky_buttons[0])
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-download__title')
        print('elements =', elements)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d1ed56ed6e0f43a470f0a24f1a4ba798", element="8e88c2a7-633d-4df9-b0de-e5e27ddc21b3")>]
elements = [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d1ed56ed6e0f43a470f0a24f1a4ba798", element="66acebf6-4971-42c5-9395-1c7913b5effd")>]
```

Comment: Well sure, it didn't give an error this time, but it didn't download what it should have either. So, on a whim, I asked it to print(lucky_button), and guess what, the list is empty (so your lucky_button[0].click() never came into play and therefore no error). Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Well, in normal mode, yes, it downloaded the file (it did throw up a "This type of file can harm your computer, keep or discard" message, but thats fine, at least it was downloading it. However, when I ran it in headless mode...nothing. Also, your code doesn't end until I input something after 'pausing...', not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see what was going on -- that's why I added the "pausing ...".

Comment: So, do you have any idea why its failing to download in headless mode, but works in normal mode?

Comment: I updated the answer again to go "headless" and to remove unwanted logging messages that Chrome puts out. After clicking on the Download button, I look for an element in the next page (class ''message-download__title') and I find it. So it seems to work for me. Note the technique I use: `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` to wait implicitly up to 5 seconds for an element to appear when doing a find operation. So when a click is done that will result in a new page being loaded, you can issue a find for an element in the next page and the driver will wait for up to 5 seconds for the next page to load.

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working on my machine. Its clicking that download button, and then going to the next page just fine, but if its actually downloading anything, its certainly not doing it in the downloads folder (where chrome generally downloads things). Did you see a file like "flashplayer32pp_ka_install.exe" in your downloads folder after running this code on your end?

Comment: Also, for me it printed (in the shell): [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e81e8d0d52cf0316bc1fcb8ea11378f5", element="18bd890f-72c2-4ee3-bbc4-d56a84dbd46f")>]
elements = [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e81e8d0d52cf0316bc1fcb8ea11378f5", element="04c13b05-c5fb-4ef4-b3dc-ee038cf4bc41")>]

Comment: I didn't take the next step of clicking further on the "keep" button to proceed further with the download (there was a message about "this type of file can harm your computer").